# How much critical CSS can be inlined before there is a negative performance impact?

Tags: seo, html, page-speed

I've heard that to avoid render-blocking issues, it's good to inline critical CSS directly in the `<HEAD>` tag by including the actual CSS in `<STYLE>` tags, and then load the rest of the CSS asynchronously.

At the other hand, I read it's bad to inline too much CSS.

Is there some limit for critical CSS after which it becomes a negative performance impact?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**As of 2011, you will see the first drop in page performance after 14.6 KB has been sent.** For the speediest page, all of your HTML code from the first byte up to and including the critical CSS should fit within this amount of data.

14.6 KB is the size of an HTTP server's [initial TCP congestion window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_congestion_control) assuming a default TCP IW value of 10 (which was agreed on for major web browsers in [RFC 6928](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6928)). This 14.6KB payload represents how much data the server can send to the client before hearing acknowledgement that the data was received (aka before waiting for the first network round-trip).

If you think of the HTTP connection as a series of boat expeditions from the server to the client, 14.6 KB is when the first explorer's ship is full, and the rest of the HTML has to sit around and wait for the cargo ships.

[image: Illustration of boats on TCP]

So if the beginning of your HTML - up until the end of your critical inlined CSS - is less than 14.6 KB, that is optimal. Due to the way TCP congestion control works (doubling the amount of data sent as each burst is acknowledged), you can send 98 KB (14 KB + 28 KB + 56 KB) within 3 round-trips - so [Google recommends that all above-the-fold content should be renderable with the first 98 KB of the document](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/mobile) for mobile page speed reasons.

In short, **14.6 KB** is the upper limit for critical inlined resources to fit within the first RTT. To fit within three RTTs and Google's recommendation, the cutoff is **98 KB**.

This answer applies to HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2, as they are both TCP-based protocols. This answer does not apply to HTTP/3, as it is a UDP-based protocol with its own inbuilt ramp-up strategy that I believe may be different than the strategy used by TCP.

Comment: Also, it would make sense to me that the 14.6 KB figure would be *after* gzipping, since the compression protocol is negotiated from the get-go in the `Accept-Encoding` request header sent with the initial HTTP request.

Comment: Amazing answer ;)

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister btw, does HTTP/2 without inlining anything completely eliminate the render-blocking issue or just reduce it?

Comment: @stckvrw On the contrary, single page performance-wise that's the same or worse than inlining (still better than 1.1 though). If you want more detailed responses I encourage you to ask a new question!

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister one more question: if critical CSS enqueues a font with `@font-face{src:url(...)}`, is it the first round trip?

Comment: @stckvrw No - Unless the font is both very small and also gets HTTP/2 pushed by the server, it will miss the first boat (I don't think there are any 14KB fonts anyways though). That's the best of my knowledge.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister and one more: if we use only inline style with size more than 14.6 KB e.g. 20 KB, is it better for SEO to keep using it all inline or better to split it to inline 14.6 and put the rest 5.4 KB in external css file?

Comment: @stckvrw For SEO I would say with pretty high confidence that it doesn't make any difference at all. For performance, the difference will be very slight and I would say 99% of the time it doesn't matter, but it might make sense in situations where a site is very lightweight and page render time is critical. In any case CSS is a render-blocking resource, so if you do decide to split it up you will need to lazy-load the external stylesheet so it doesn't block, or it would defeat the purpose.

Comment: Is there some update related to your answer due to modern approaches for example HTTP/2 and HTTP/3 ?

Comment: @stckvrw HTTP/2 is still a TCP-based connection, so the answer still applies. HTTP/3 is a UDP-based connection, so this answer does not apply.